# Mujoco installation, binaries not found

Tags: python, mujoco

I'm in trouble for installing mujoco.

I folows the steps at https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/253.

Everything worked correctly, but when I had to run "python examples\body_interaction.py" I'm having an issue :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\mujoco-py\examples\body_interaction.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mujoco_py import load_model_from_xml, MjSim, MjViewer
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\venv\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    init_config()
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\venv\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\config.py", line 37, in init_config
    raise error.MujocoDependencyError('Found your MuJoCo license key but not binaries. Please put your binaries into ~/.mujoco/mjpro131 or set MUJOCO_PY_MJPRO_PATH. Follow the instructions on https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py for
 setup.')
mujoco_py.error.MujocoDependencyError: Found your MuJoCo license key but not binaries. Please put your binaries into ~/.mujoco/mjpro131 or set MUJOCO_PY_MJPRO_PATH. Follow the instructions on https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py for
 setup.
```

This is how my .mujoco directory looks like:

[image]

And mujoco200 is the directory i downloaded from there: https://www.roboti.us/index.html for win64,

This is how my Env variables looks like:

[image]

To solve this, I tried to download "mjpro131 win64" from [there](https://www.roboti.us/index.html), and add it to the env. variables using name "MUJOCO_PY_MJPRO_PATH", but then it gave me an other error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\mujoco-py\examples\body_interaction.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mujoco_py import load_model_from_xml, MjSim, MjViewer
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\venv\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .mjviewer import MjViewer
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\venv\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\mjviewer.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import mjcore, mjconstants, glfw
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\venv\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\mjcore.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .mjlib import mjlib
  File "D:\Session User\Desktop\computing\stage2021_hedwinb\venv\lib\site-packages\mujoco_py\mjlib.py", line 21, in <module>
    mjlib = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.abspath(libfile))
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 452, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide
```

Last line translation:

```
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 Is not a valid win32 application.
```

I Also tried with the win32 achive, but it gave me the exact same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem in Linux. I decided to download the 0.5.7 version of mujoco

```
pip install mujoco-py==0.5.7
```

and then changed the requirements to

```
click==7.0
xmltodict==0.12.0
scipy==1.3.1
gym==0.10.8
jsonnet==0.11.2
numpy
mujoco-py==0.5.7
```

Here's another link for instructions : [installing mujoco](https://neptune.ai/blog/installing-mujoco-to-work-with-openai-gym-environments)